# Set size proportional to x and y axis

Tags: echarts, bubble-chart

The x axis, y axis and size are dependent on 3 fields whose values are dynamic:

x: population

y: GDP

size: land area

There's a symbolSize property in option where we can set the bubble size, but I'm not sure what formula to use so size is proportional to x and y axis values.

```
symbolSize: (d: any) => {
    return d[2];
},
```

Comment: Was my assumption (in my answer) correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try Pythagoreas :

> x^2 + y^2

If you want the growth to be linear :

> sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

Comment: (this is pseudo code)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking how to scale the bubble sizes so they do not cover too much of the graph:

size_scaled = f*((x_max - x_min)*(y_max - y_min))*size/size_max

where f is the fraction of the graph to be covered by the largest bubble.

f = 0.01 => 1% of the graph will be covered by the largest bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the phrasing you've used, this may not be what you're looking for, but I came across this post while trying to do something similar in ECharts and figured a post here might help others.

In my case, I didn't want bubble size to be proportional to the x- and y-axis values, as you've mentioned above, but each row in my data includes a value that should be used for relative sizing of the bubbles, similar to your "land area" field.

What I needed was a generic `symbolSize` function that could work for different incoming data sets with different magnitudes of values.

For example, in one dataset, maybe `symbolSize` should be calculated by "population" (i.e., 1500000, 2000000, etc.) and, down the road, maybe I'd be charting with a dataset that has that populate scaled down to "populationInBillions" (i.e., .0015, .002). I needed a generic function that could handle both.

*Note: one assumption is the series data should be relatively uniform. If you have a mix of very large and very small values, this may not work well.*

```js
// First, settle on some min/max bubble sizes that work well for your chart
const BUBBLE_MIN_SIZE = 10;
const BUBBLE_MAX_SIZE = 75;

// Square them because we'll eventually use `Math.sqrt`
// See https://chartio.com/learn/charts/bubble-chart-complete-guide/#scale-bubble-area-by-value
const squaredMax = Math.pow(BUBBLE_MAX_SIZE, 2);
const squaredMin = Math.pow(BUBBLE_MIN_SIZE, 2);

// Index of the field in your data that represents the bubble size
const bubbleSizeIdx = 2;

// Find min and max values in your data for the column
const minValue = Math.min(...data);
const maxValue = Math.max(...data);

const seriesData = series.map((singleSeries) => {
  singleSeries.symbolSize = (dataItem): number => {
    // Scales each bubble so it's sized relative to the mix and max values in the dataset
    const scale = (dataItem[bubbleSizeIdx] - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);
    const scaledSize = scale * (squaredMax - squaredMin) + squaredMin;
    return Math.sqrt(scaledSize);
  };

  return singleSeries;
});
```